# How to apply multiple object property to ngStyle

Tags: angular, ng-style

I have an element in my HTML like this:
 `<span [ngStyle]="{'background': getColor(selectedOption.type)}">BLAH</span>`

I have a condition in my TS file like this:

```
public getColor(type: string){

        switch (type) {
        case 'General':
            return {background: '#ffe5d7', color: '#e7560a' };
        case 'Interview':
            return { background: '#ffe5d7', color: '#e7560a' };
//more code
```

Basically, if the user selects "General", I want the correct background AND font color to be returned from the function and applied to the element using ngStyle. But this isn't working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try <span [ngStyle]="getColor(selectedOption.type)">BLAH</span> or delete background from your return statement. Because you are duplicating background two times. Similarly you should also delete the brackets from return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span [ngStyle]="getColor(selectedOption?.type)">BLAH</span>

public getColor(type: string | undefined){

   if (type) {

      switch (type) {
        case 'General':
            return {background: '#ffe5d7', color: '#e7560a' };
        case 'Interview':
            return { background: '#ffe5d7', color: '#e7560a' };
        //more code

        case default:
            return {};
 
   }

return {};
}
```

EDIT: I've just read @Onur Baştürk had answerd before me.
He was right, you were duplicating the **background** attribute,
one in the HTML ([ngStyle]="{'background':...) and another in your ts code:

```
return {background: '#ffe5d7', color: '#e7560a' ....
```

Comment: This does not work. I am getting this error: Type '{ background: string; color: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; } | null'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; } | null'.

Comment: I've just edit my answer. Do you have in your switch a 'default' case? If not, add it as I've done in my edit code. And take care of the new '?.' that I put in the html code, and the "if (type)" as well

Comment: Also, note that this answer correctly uses ngStyle. Use of ngClass as specified in the OP is incorrect since that expects a `Record<cssClassName, booleanish>` object.